# determine which page an object is on in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport, tableofcontents

I need to do this for a 'Table of Contents' (sub)report.

Methinks it is not possible.

Any ideas?

e.g.
Table 1 starts on page 2
Table 2 starts on page 7

Is there, perhaps, a way of tapping into the Document Map?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely clear on waht you are trying to do but

```
=Globals!PageNumber
```

may help?

Comment: It's for a table of contents! :)
Seriously though, I need to determine what page an object starts on.
Globals!PageNumber only returns the current page number

Comment: I thought you could put a hidden textbox on a page with that expression and then get it's value for you table of contents. However, it appears that expression only works in the header or footer. I guess it is because RS does not even know what page the body is on.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

(Why isn't there an option in the 'close question' link to highlight as 'no answer possible'?)